# Raspberri Pi (Raspian) running Apache 2, PhP(7) HTML CSS not running PHP

Tags: raspbian, php, apache-httpd, html5

I am getting very frustrated with trying to track down the source of my problems with the code below. I believe it is something to do with php files not being run. (Note that all files are in the same directory, with sudo access to each other. It is currently displaying a white screen on the following code. All other code sections that are not relevant have not been shown here) and due to me just starting to learn PHP, I am confused as to where this issue is originating.
index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <title> Test Server - Rasp 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include('header.php');?>
<div class="body_hold">
    <div class="row">       
        <div class = "column leftm"> 
            <h2> Left </h2>
        </div>

        <div class = "column middlem" style="height: 100%;"> 
            <h2> Welcome to... </h2>
            <h1> Tegarn Empire Home</h1>
            <p> This is a test paragraph!!! <br> <br> <br></p>
        </div>

        <div class = "column rightm"> 
            <h2> Right </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include('footer.php');?>
```

Here's Header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <div class="header main">
            <img src="media/tgelogo.png" class="logo"> 
            <div class="header-right">
                <a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a>
                <a href="contact-us.php"> Contact Us</a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <p> End of header...</p>
```

And here's footer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="footer">
    <p> This Website is property of the Tegarn Empire. </p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The css file for this is quite extensive... (I saved it as txt by accident, but on the server, its actually .css: https://pastebin.com/VfRYSWf0

I have tried everything I can think of. By the way, before I started using PHP and kept it all in one HTML script, it was working fine.

Comment: Welcome to SE RPi Jerry. I would be surprised if the browser likes coming across the DOCTYPE in the header and footer like that.

Comment: This question should be migrated to webmaster forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the browser is getting thrown by the DOCTYPE's in the header and footer. It should not need to see them because it knows `index.html` is an HTML document.

I would remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` from both PHP include files and put the HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration at the start of your `index.html` instead.

Comment: It still shows me a white screen. (Both before and after I removed the tags) - what could be going on? @Mike Poole

Comment: I don't know what I did, but I did something and it fixed it; no idea how or why. Thanks for the suggestion - I think it may have solved one of my issues.

Comment: @JerryPlayz101 that is great news. Always glad to help.

Comment: This doesn't answer a question to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: The OP asked the question so I helped them by answering it. If you are objecting because you view the question as off topic surely that is something to bring up with the OP rather than with someone who wants to help them. Why is it that this stack seems to have several veterans who seem more interested in procedures than in helping new members asking and answering questions?

Comment: I am hosting the code on a Raspberry Pi, and that is why this question is relevant. If its a problem with the installation of a module, that makes it a Pi issue.